# Amazon ec2 Public IP not loading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

I have had an ec2 instance for about 3-4 months, it was working fine. I came back to make some edits and something broke. When I go to the url, it didn't load, so I tried the Public IP, and that also times out. I'm new to this - what could be wrong?

Comment: You should post some code indicating what you mean.

Comment: General things to look at that can help us understand your problem:
- In the console are you using the correct public IP (if these aren't elastic IPs they change on a restart of the instance)
- Does the security group your instance is in allow access
- Does the subnet your instance in have an internet gateway?

Comment: `I came back to make some edits`. May we know the `edits` ?